# Number of functions that give $|G| = n$ a group structure

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory

While studying group theory I began asking myself the following question:

> Let $G$ a set such that $|G| = n$. How many function $G \times G \to G$ give $G$ a group structure?

The number of total functions from $G \times G \to G$ is $n^{(n^2)}$ and I tried using combinatorics and arrived at the conclusion that the number of functions that have an unique identity element is:
$$n \cdot(n-1)^{n-1} \cdot n^{n^2 - 3n + 2}$$

But the thing is that I'm not being able to use the same combinatorial approach to the associative property.

How can this be solved?

Comment: Exactly the bijections.

Comment: But it's impossible to have a bijection from $G /times G /to G$ @Wuestenfux

Comment: Composition of functions

Comment: what do you mean by "composition of functions"?  @Wuestenfux

Comment: https://oeis.org/A034383 is the sequence you're looking for. If $n$ is prime, then $a(n) = n!/(n-1)$, but it is not as simple for composite $n$.

Comment: See also this [related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1107534/given-a-finite-set-how-to-generate-all-possible-groups-defined-on-it), for constructing all possible group structures.

Comment: This is similar to asking how many isomorphism types there are of groups of order $n$, except that we are summing $|{\rm Aut}(G_i)|$ over the representatives $G_i$ of the isomorphism types. I suspect that the problem is at least as difficult, even (or perhaps particularly) in the case when $n$ is a prime power.

Comment: @EduardoMagalhães Your effort is futile. There is no known closed formula for the exact number of groups of order $n$, whether up to isomorphism or not. There are some results assuming specific $n$ (e.g. when it is prime power) and there are some approximations on general $n$, but no exact formula is known.